# How to open maps and calls using ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH

Tags: android, artificial-intelligence, speech-recognition

I am developing a code in which the app takes input as speech and does the specific tasks.

I have got the code from changing speech to text but I am not able to put a if condition to create calls or open maps

here is a piece of code after getting text

```
case RESULT_SPEECH: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                ArrayList<String> text = data
                        .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                Text.setText(text.get(0));
                String check = text.get(0);
                if(check.equals("call")){
                    System.out.println("yes calling");
                }
            }
            break;
        }
```

Here I am performing if condition if he says call it should print "yes calling" but its not printing. what should I do?

Comment: Have you done any debugging?  Is this function being called at all?  Is RESULT_SPEECH being returned?  Is the result code RESULT_OK?  Is data being returned?  Is the recognition returning the correct words?  Do the ground work, then we may be able to help you.

Comment: Yeah everything is okay, getting the RESULT_SPEECH everything is done, but if statement is not getting executed.

Answer (score 1):

Okay you can do it.

```
case RESULT_SPEECH: {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            ArrayList<String> text = data
                    .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            Text.setText(text.get(0));
            String check = text.get(0);
            if(check.equals("call")){
                 Intent intent = new Intent(package name for app);
                 try{    
                 startActivity(intent);
                 }catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){
                 }
            }
        }
        break;
    }
```